Keyboard keys combos broken on Kubuntu 24
After reinstalling Kubuntu, many key combos are broken like: ctrl+shift+v and ctrl+shift+c for terminal use, ctrl+maj+left for back word selection, ctrl+shift+p shortcut configured in my VsCode, Alt Gr + k, and Alt Gr + i shortcut configured in my IntelliJ, etc.
As it occurs in many different software, I suppose it's related to my OS configuration, probably the keyboard layout.
Specifications:

OS: Kbuntu 24.04 with KDE Plasma 5.27.11. With my previous installation on Kubuntu 22, it worked correctly.
Laptop: Thinkpad X1 carbon
Keyboard layout: Azerty
Keyboard model: Generic | Generic 105-key PC

I've tried to change the keyboard model to different values without success.
When I open the Keyboard Layout Viewer, Alt Gr + k is correctly highlighted but not ctrl+shift+v where the v doesn't highlight.
That being said, where should I deep dive to find the origin of this issue? What could be at cause?
